# visual-c++ [VECTOR] The date stored in vector cannot be found

Tags: visual-c++

So, I had my dates stored as a string, and loop through it but it cannot find the matching date from the vector. To make sure it loops through the vector, I put else at the bottom there and for every time it loops through the vector and is not found the date will display it.

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA17B.png

```
cout << "Please enter a date: ";

                 cin >> searchByDate;
                 for (columnCount = 0; columnCount < currentRow; columnCount++)
                 {
                     if (searchByDate == DATE[columnCount])  
                     {
                         cout << DATE[columnCount] << "\t" << CUSTNAME[columnCount] << "\t" << GENDER[columnCount] << "\t" << IDENTITY[columnCount] << "\t";
                         cout << TELEPHONE[columnCount] << "\t" << TYPE[columnCount] << "\t" << THERAPIST[columnCount] << "\t" << CHARGES[columnCount] << endl;
                         totalRevenue += CHARGES[columnCount];
                     }
                     else
                         cout << "date 404";
```

Help! Emergency!

Comment: Well, apparently, there is no element in the `DATE` array that compares equal to the string `2/1/2021` For further assistance, prepare a [mcve].

Comment: ahh, I did a vector for it, and apparently, the problem is the input file, and I solved the problem, thanks for looking up!